# HTTP forward app-engine traffic to vm in GCP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I created a nodejs app in the compute engine istening to port 8080 and I have a VM which is running an HTTP server.

Whenever I clock on .appspot.com. I want all the traffic to be routed to port 8080 on VM.

My VM is running a HTTP server

Comment: What do you mean by forwarding HTTP traffic? Do you mean redirect, proxy or tunnel? Edit your question with details and the problem you are solving.

Comment: done, I edited my question. IDK if I need to create a node server in compute engine or not

Comment: Assuming this is an Internal set up you may refer on this [Internal TCP/UDP load balancer components](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal#configure_the_load_balancer). See also full details of [TCP/UDP Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal)  and [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) for other options.